# Passing color codes from bash variables through sed

Tags: bash, sed, ansi-escape

I have a little problem with sed in bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 clear

 DAY=$(date -d "$D" '+%d')
 MONTH=$(date -d "$D" '+%m')
 YEAR=$(date -d "$D" '+%Y')
 RED='\033[0;31m'
 NC='\033[0m' # No Color

 cal  >> plik1.txt

 echo "ni po wt sr cz pi so"
 awk '{if(NR>2)print}' plik1.txt | sed s/$DAY/${RED}${DAY}${NC}/g

 echo "Miesiac: $MONTH Rok: $YEAR Dzien: $DAY"

 rm plik1.txt
```

Sed doesn't change color. Any idea?

Comment: As http://shellcheck.net/ would point out, btw, you're missing double quotes around expansions. Not going to cause trouble in this specific case, but if you had whitespace in your format strings, or glob expressions, it would; the better practice is to double-quote expansions in all cases where you don't have a specific reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Also, all-caps variable names are reserved for variables impacting (or provided by) the operating system and the shell; it's best practice to use lower-case names for your own variables. See fourth paragraph of  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as you are currently using awk incorrectly. You will be amazed...

Answer (score 4):

`\033` isn't treated specially by the shell inside normal quotes. Use ANSI quoting.

```
RED=$'\033[0;31m'
NC=$'\033[0m' # No Color
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give what you are looking for :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 clear
 day=$(date -d "$D" '+%d')
 echo "DAY : "$day
 month=$(date -d "$D" '+%m')
 year=$(date -d "$D" '+%Y')
 red=$'\033[0;31m'
 nc=$'\033[0m'

 echo "ni po wt sr cz pi so"
 awk '{if(NR>2)print}' <(cal -h) | sed "s/$day/${red}${day}${nc}/"
 echo "Miesiac: $month Rok: $year Dzien: $day"
```

**Courtesy:**

1. `cal -h` tip from @cyrus - This was critical.
2. The ANSI quoting tip from @chepner - This was critical.
3. Lowercase variable names from @charles-duffy - Best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Add option `-h` to command `cal` to disable cal's own highlighting of today.

See: `cal | cat -A` and `cal -h | cat -A`

Comment: The way I read it, the OP is trying to *add* highlighting, as opposed to removing it.

Comment: Yes. `cal` highlights its output without option -h. It's necessary to disable cal's own highlighting of todays "23" before sed can find "23" and replace it with ANSI-codes. See: `cal | cat -A`

Comment: Ahh! Explaining the relevance of your answer is helpful. :)

Comment: @Cyrus : comment#2 was a nice touch. Enlightened !!